# Get a good grip on

Tags: vocabulary

I read a sentence:

> Like I said earlier, it’s totally worth spending some time getting a good grip on how key funcs work in Python.

Get a grip in [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/get_a_grip) means:
Keep or recover one's self-control. but it doesn't make sense.

I guess 'getting a good grip' means 'learning' in the context.

Is it a good practice to use 'get a grip' as synonyms of 'learn'?

Comment: The word [*grasp*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/grasp) means "To take hold of intellectually; comprehend", and sometimes its synonym (*grip*) can likewise be used in this figurative context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple idiom:

- [get a grip on something](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-a-grip-on-something) - *to begin to understand a difficult situation and start to find a way of dealing with it* *(To have a newfound understanding of a topic or concept)*

Comment: Thank you very much.I have dictionaries of Cambridge, Collins, MW, Oxford, Dictionary.com, urban dictionary ,etymology.com and the dict you recommend Macmillan Dict.

Comment: @YumiTada - [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+a+grip) is quite good for idioms.